# Why are Linux versions so confusing?

Tags: linux, kernel, version

I was browsing through kernel.org pages and reading changelogs from several different Linux kernel versions. I noticed the version number pattern is extremely awkward:

From Linux 2.6.x came Linux 3.0;

After it reached 3.19 it became 4.0;

The 4.x version is getting new versions at a surprisingly fast pace: Ubuntu 15.10 used 4.2 and 16.04 will use 4.4! In the meantime, 4.5 is already in the "release candidate" stage. But the 3.x kernel had such a slow version number progression!

What is happening? Did the Linux kernel suddenly get a few thousand new developers? Is there some special reason for the different version numbers among the releases?

Comment: Your question certainly is answered at the kernel.org faq-page https://www.kernel.org/category/faq.html

Comment: No, didn't get an answer from there...

Comment: You are confusing confusing and surprising. Linux version numbering is consistent and linear so there is nothing confusing. You are just surprised by the pace change. What would have been confusing is for example, jumping from version 3 to version 8, then to version B5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to move from 3.19 to 4.0 is just to keep things simple. There was a public poll and discussion about that. I believe this is the poll: https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/jmtzzLiiejc

So yes, linux kernel is rapidly developed and those switching is just in order to keep things simple.

Comment: But then why 2.x and 3.x had so much point releases and took ages to be released?

Comment: Please check the link (answer updated): https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/jmtzzLiiejc and check what Linus Torvalds saying.

Answer (score 1):

Before Linux 3.x, the version numbering scheme was:
`major.major-rev.minor-rev`, with the `major` number only incrementing with rewrite-level changes, the `major-rev` increasing on major changes (even numbers for stable, odd for experimental, until 2.6, when the development started taking place in one branch). `minor-rev` used to increment for new features / drivers (there was also a bug fix number afterwards)

Later a decision was made to move to 3.x and increment the second number every few months (when adding features). The third digit now indicates the bug fix. (The level of change between 3.2 and 3.3 is much closer to the difference between 2.6.11 and 2.6.12, than the difference between 2.4 and 2.5 (experimental that became 2.6))

As per the other answer, the increment from 3.x to 4.x occurred by poll.

(via linfo.org and Wikipedia)

About the pace, a few random years as samples:

- There were 5 2.6.x releases in 2008
- There were 5 3.x releases in 2013 (6 in 2012 and 2014)
- There were 6 4.x releases in 2016 (4 in 2015, but 3.19 was also in 2015)